# Конвертровать string[] в char[,]

Tags: c#, строки, char, конвертация

Есть некоторый массив строк:

```
var strArr = new string[]
{
    "qwer",
    "asdf",
    "zxcv"
};
```

при условии, что я уверен, что все вложенные строки одинакового размера.

Нужно как-то конвертировать это в:

```
var chars = new char[,]
{
    {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'},
    {'a', 's', 'd', 'f'},
    {'z', 'x', 'c', 'v'}
}
```

максимально простыми методами, желательно без велосипедов.

Comment: а что мешает использовать .ToCharArray()?

Comment: в чём состоит проблема написать двойной цикл (цикл в цикле), где вы будете в одном из них (цикле) перебирать строки, а в другом (во внутреннем) перебирать символы данной строки (которые имеют тип char) и присваивать их соответствующему элементу двумерного массива char'ов?

Comment: @ArtemLP Ну нельзя ли это сделать как-то более красиво, с помощью всяких `Array`, `ForEach`, и всего такого, чтобы можно было вообще в одной строчке записать?

Comment: @VladimirT, `Select + ToCharArray` даст массив массивов, двумерный массив таким способом не получить. Только ручками в цикле заполнять. С другой стороны не понятно, зачем автору это вообще нужно, если читать, то читать можно и так `strArr[1][2]`.

Comment: @Prunkles, массив массивов — можно, двумерный массив — нет.

Comment: Тогда я совсем не понимаю в чем вопрос, может стоит разъяснить что конкретно имеет в виду автор?

Comment: @Prunkles, красиво будет выделить этот код в функцию. Этого вполне достаточно, учитывая, что он будет состоить из нескольких строк.

Comment: @VladimirT Написать *максимально маленькую по кол-ву кода* программку, которая конвертировала бы массив строк (`string[]`) в двумерный массив (не массив массивов) чаров (`char[,]`).

Comment: Я бы сделал через Linq: `var x = strArr.Select(str => str.ToCharArray()).ToArray();`. И, возможно, избавился бы от лишних приведений (если вам не критичен IEnumerable)

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F Вооот, практически идеально, и то что нужно, но... Это массив массивов `char[][]`, а можно ли его конвертировать в `char[,]`?

Comment: "максимально маленькую" - минимальную?

Answer (score 0):

Объединять строки, в массив и копировать.

```
string[] strArr = ...;
int x = strArr.Length;
int y = strArr[0].Length;
char[,] chars = new char[x, y];
Buffer.BlockCopy(String.Concat(strArr).ToCharArray(), 0, chars, 0, x * y * 2);
```

В конце умножается на два, потому что char занимает 2 байта.